# json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field .Amount of type string

Tags: json, go

Trying to get balance of Tron wallet using tronscan.org

Sometimes Amount returns string, sometimes value like this

```json
"amount": 1.4900288469458728E-8
```

When it returns value of this type i get this error `json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field .Amount of type string`

Here is my struct:

```golang
type trxResponse struct {
  Data []struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount,string"`
  } `json:"data"`
}
```

How can I handle it? To unmarshal json i'm using https://github.com/goccy/go-json

Comment: 1.4900288469458728E-8 is float64, not string, remove `string` from your struct

Comment: @RahmatFathoni Does it matter that the value of `Amount`, according to OP, _can sometimes be a string_ (apparently)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the amount field has different types, it can be declared as `interface{}` type, this will solve unmarshaling error.

```
type trxResponse struct {
  Data []struct {
    Amount interface{} `json:"amount"`
  } `json:"data"`
}
```

This can then be typecast from/to `float64` or `string` as needed..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface by declaring custom `UnmarshalJSON` method, which will handle the amount field according to the type.

```
type trxData struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
}

type trxResponse struct {
    Data []trxData `json:"data"`
}

// UnmarshalJSON custom method for handling different types
// of the amount field.
func (d *trxData) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var objMap map[string]*json.RawMessage

    // unmarshal json to raw messages
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &objMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var amount float64 // try to unmarshal to float64
    if rawMsg, ok := objMap["amount"]; ok {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(*rawMsg, &amount); err != nil {
            // if failed, unmarshal to string
            var amountStr string
            if err := json.Unmarshal(*rawMsg, &amountStr); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            amount, err = strconv.ParseFloat(amountStr, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    d.Amount = amount

    return nil
}
```